# Significantly reduced page performance using Cloudflare proxy

Tags: cloudflare

I have been using Cloudflare for a while, however I am having an issue where I am getting significantly increased page loading times measured both on Google PageSpeed Insights and on Google Chrome.

**Without it being Proxied:**

[image: Google PageSpeed Insights]
[image: Google Chrome]

**With it being Proxied by Cloudflare:**

[image: Google PageSpeed Insights]
[image: Google Chrome]

As you can see, there's a 45% decrease in Google PageSpeed Insights score, but in addition the Google Chrome loading times are over twice as long!

This is a **drastic** performance hit. I really like using Cloudflare but I can't afford to take such a drastic performance hit. I even went as far as setting up a staging subdomain on the same server with the same content, but opted to not have that proxied. The results consistently replicable.

Do I have something misconfigured?

Edit:

Here is comparative tests using webpagetest.org:

**Staging/No Proxy:**
[image: Staging/No CDN]

**Proxied by Cloudflare CDN:**
[image: Proxied by Cloudflare CDN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with Cloudflare's RocketLoader, I disabled that and then disabled some tags on GTM.